# Superimposed curves in two regions

Tags: mathematical-optimization, code-request

If I have several data set like the following (I am showing just two):

```
data1 = {{0.043026`, -1.574246`}, {0.545`, -1.645566`}, {1.046`, \
-1.6726`}, {1.544`, -1.60482`}, {2.033`, -1.196952`}, {2.521`, \
-0.744032`}, {3.009`, -0.3334`}, {3.499`, 0.022269`}, {3.993`, 
    0.25591`}, {4.487`, 0.461728`}, {4.982`, 0.6502`}, {5.476`, 
    0.830412`}, {5.972`, 0.988042`}, {6.468`, 1.130558`}, {6.964`, 
    1.254558`}, {7.461`, 1.366148`}, {7.958`, 1.452664`}, {8.456`, 
    1.53088`}, {8.954`, 1.600648`}, {9.452`, 1.664894`}, {9.95`, 
    1.715022`}, {10.449`, 1.760686`}, {10.947`, 1.800224`}, {11.446`, 
    1.836156`}, {11.945`, 1.864578`}, {12.444`, 1.889808`}, {12.943`, 
    1.912624`}, {13.443`, 1.932432`}, {13.942`, 1.948548`}, {14.441`, 
    1.96331`}, {14.941`, 1.976404`}, {15.44`, 1.988352`}, {15.94`, 
    1.99745`}, {16.439`, 2.0057`}, {16.939`, 2.01302`}, {17.438`, 
    2.01996`}, {17.938`, 2.02594`}, {18.438`, 2.03164`}, {18.937`, 
    2.0367`}, {19.437`, 2.04118`}, {19.937`, 2.04498`}, {20.436`, 
    2.0491`}, {20.936`, 2.05316`}, {21.436`, 2.05684`}, {21.936`, 
    2.06002`}, {22.435`, 2.06284`}, {22.935`, 2.06558`}, {23.435`, 
    2.06844`}, {23.935`, 2.07094`}, {24.434`, 2.07358`}, {24.934`, 
    2.07626`}, {25.434`, 2.07894`}, {25.933`, 2.08148`}, {26.433`, 
    2.08406`}, {26.933`, 2.08668`}, {27.433`, 2.08936`}, {27.932`, 
    2.09196`}, {28.432`, 2.09446`}, {28.932`, 2.09696`}, {29.432`, 
    2.09952`}, {29.931`, 2.10198`}, {30.431`, 2.1044`}, {30.931`, 
    2.10678`}, {31.43`, 2.10916`}, {31.93`, 2.11148`}, {32.43`, 
    2.11392`}, {32.93`, 2.11648`}, {33.429`, 2.11908`}, {33.929`, 
    2.12176`}, {34.429`, 2.12444`}, {34.929`, 2.12718`}, {35.428`, 
    2.12992`}, {35.928`, 2.13282`}, {36.428`, 2.13568`}, {36.927`, 
    2.1386`}, {37.427`, 2.14158`}, {37.927`, 2.1448`}, {38.427`, 
    2.14808`}, {38.926`, 2.15146`}, {39.426`, 2.1549`}, {39.926`, 
    2.15876`}, {40.425`, 2.16254`}, {40.925`, 2.16642`}, {41.425`, 
    2.17044`}, {41.924`, 2.17456`}, {42.424`, 2.17882`}, {42.924`, 
    2.1836`}, {43.423`, 2.18866`}, {43.923`, 2.19424`}, {44.422`, 
    2.19958`}, {44.922`, 2.20498`}, {45.422`, 2.2105`}, {45.921`, 
    2.21632`}, {46.421`, 2.22202`}, {46.92`, 2.22768`}, {47.42`, 
    2.23328`}, {47.92`, 2.23882`}, {48.419`, 2.24422`}, {48.919`, 
    2.2495`}, {49.418`, 2.2547`}, {49.918`, 2.25946`}, {50.418`, 
    2.26434`}, {50.917`, 2.26924`}, {51.417`, 2.27414`}, {51.917`, 
    2.27898`}, {52.416`, 2.2839`}, {52.916`, 2.28882`}, {53.415`, 
    2.29376`}, {53.915`, 2.29888`}, {54.415`, 2.30394`}, {54.914`, 
    2.30904`}, {55.414`, 2.31424`}, {55.913`, 2.31968`}, {56.413`, 
    2.32508`}, {56.913`, 2.33034`}, {57.412`, 2.33602`}, {57.912`, 
    2.34284`}, {58.411`, 2.34992`}, {58.911`, 2.35758`}, {59.41`, 
    2.36582`}, {59.91`, 2.37464`}, {60.409`, 2.38342`}, {60.909`, 
    2.39274`}, {61.408`, 2.4023`}, {61.907`, 2.41414`}, {62.407`, 
    2.4259`}, {62.906`, 2.43778`}, {63.405`, 2.44992`}, {63.904`, 
    2.4626`}, {64.404`, 2.4757`}, {64.903`, 2.48946`}, {65.402`, 
    2.50388`}, {65.901`, 2.51898`}, {66.401`, 2.53372`}, {66.9`, 
    2.54852`}, {67.399`, 2.56342`}, {67.898`, 2.5786`}, {68.397`, 
    2.59364`}, {68.896`, 2.60864`}, {69.396`, 2.62358`}, {69.895`, 
    2.63842`}, {70.394`, 2.65312`}, {70.893`, 2.66768`}, {71.392`, 
    2.68214`}, {71.891`, 2.69612`}, {72.391`, 2.71022`}, {72.89`, 
    2.72404`}, {73.389`, 2.73784`}, {73.888`, 2.75074`}, {74.388`, 
    2.76274`}, {74.887`, 2.77374`}, {75.386`, 2.78436`}, {75.885`, 
    2.7941`}, {76.385`, 2.80288`}, {76.884`, 2.81026`}, {77.384`, 
    2.8168`}, {77.883`, 2.82128`}, {78.383`, 2.82508`}, {78.883`, 
    2.82772`}, {79.382`, 2.8294`}, {79.882`, 2.83008`}, {80.382`, 
    2.83054`}, {80.881`, 2.83042`}, {81.381`, 2.82966`}, {81.881`, 
    2.8291`}, {82.381`, 2.8286`}, {82.881`, 2.82814`}, {83.38`, 
    2.82772`}, {83.88`, 2.8275`}, {84.38`, 2.82736`}, {84.88`, 
    2.82722`}, {85.379`, 2.8273`}, {85.879`, 2.82826`}, {86.379`, 
    2.82892`}, {86.878`, 2.83`}, {87.378`, 2.8314`}, {87.878`, 
    2.83302`}, {88.377`, 2.83444`}, {88.877`, 2.83584`}, {89.377`, 
    2.83718`}, {89.877`, 2.83842`}, {90.376`, 2.83978`}, {90.876`, 
    2.84118`}, {91.376`, 2.84254`}, {91.875`, 2.84412`}, {92.375`, 
    2.84584`}, {92.875`, 2.84824`}, {93.374`, 2.85122`}, {93.874`, 
    2.85394`}, {94.373`, 2.8565`}, {94.873`, 2.85904`}, {95.373`, 
    2.86154`}, {95.872`, 2.8638`}, {96.372`, 2.86616`}, {96.872`, 
    2.86852`}, {97.371`, 2.87088`}, {97.871`, 2.8732`}, {98.371`, 
    2.87558`}, {98.87`, 2.87798`}, {99.37`, 2.88046`}, {99.87`, 
    2.88314`}, {100.369`, 2.88584`}, {100.869`, 2.88862`}, {101.368`, 
    2.89144`}, {101.868`, 2.89456`}, {102.368`, 2.89756`}, {102.867`, 
    2.9005`}, {103.367`, 2.90338`}, {103.867`, 2.90626`}, {104.366`, 
    2.90904`}, {104.866`, 2.91176`}, {105.365`, 2.91444`}, {105.865`, 
    2.9168`}, {106.365`, 2.91928`}, {106.864`, 2.92176`}, {107.364`, 
    2.9242`}, {107.864`, 2.9265`}, {108.363`, 2.9289`}, {108.863`, 
    2.93132`}, {109.362`, 2.93376`}, {109.862`, 2.93616`}, {110.362`, 
    2.93858`}, {110.861`, 2.94094`}, {111.361`, 2.94332`}, {111.861`, 
    2.9458`}, {112.36`, 2.94836`}, {112.86`, 2.95102`}, {113.36`, 
    2.95376`}, {113.859`, 2.95666`}, {114.359`, 2.95982`}, {114.858`, 
    2.96324`}, {115.358`, 2.96688`}, {115.857`, 2.97066`}, {116.357`, 
    2.97454`}, {116.857`, 2.97846`}, {117.356`, 2.98238`}, {117.856`, 
    2.98638`}, {118.355`, 2.99042`}, {118.855`, 2.9941`}, {119.354`, 
    2.9975`}, {119.854`, 3.0014`}};
```

and

```
data2 = {{0.041351`, -1.512954`}, {0.544`, -1.602904`}, {1.046`, \
-1.65819`}, {1.543`, -1.561904`}, {2.036`, -1.315522`}, {2.525`, \
-0.884998`}, {3.014`, -0.494576`}, {3.505`, -0.1774742`}, {3.997`, 
    0.0909344`}, {4.492`, 0.292358`}, {4.986`, 0.484162`}, {5.481`, 
    0.666418`}, {5.976`, 0.841728`}, {6.472`, 0.989212`}, {6.968`, 
    1.120504`}, {7.465`, 1.235154`}, {7.961`, 1.339794`}, {8.459`, 
    1.424914`}, {8.957`, 1.502186`}, {9.454`, 1.569686`}, {9.952`, 
    1.631636`}, {10.451`, 1.68123`}, {10.949`, 1.726094`}, {11.448`, 
    1.765148`}, {11.947`, 1.800996`}, {12.446`, 1.82856`}, {12.945`, 
    1.854272`}, {13.444`, 1.877312`}, {13.943`, 1.898508`}, {14.443`, 
    1.915984`}, {14.942`, 1.931`}, {15.441`, 1.944522`}, {15.941`, 
    1.957114`}, {16.44`, 1.967054`}, {16.94`, 1.975994`}, {17.44`, 
    1.983824`}, {17.939`, 1.99139`}, {18.439`, 1.99792`}, {18.938`, 
    2.00366`}, {19.438`, 2.00906`}, {19.938`, 2.0142`}, {20.437`, 
    2.01796`}, {20.937`, 2.02204`}, {21.437`, 2.02588`}, {21.937`, 
    2.02918`}, {22.436`, 2.0313`}, {22.936`, 2.03358`}, {23.436`, 
    2.0357`}, {23.936`, 2.03792`}, {24.435`, 2.0398`}, {24.935`, 
    2.04186`}, {25.435`, 2.04396`}, {25.935`, 2.04606`}, {26.434`, 
    2.04802`}, {26.934`, 2.0499`}, {27.434`, 2.05176`}, {27.934`, 
    2.05364`}, {28.433`, 2.05532`}, {28.933`, 2.05714`}, {29.433`, 
    2.05896`}, {29.933`, 2.06078`}, {30.432`, 2.06276`}, {30.932`, 
    2.06468`}, {31.432`, 2.06662`}, {31.932`, 2.06856`}, {32.431`, 
    2.07058`}, {32.931`, 2.07264`}, {33.431`, 2.0748`}, {33.931`, 
    2.07704`}, {34.43`, 2.07946`}, {34.93`, 2.0819`}, {35.43`, 
    2.08452`}, {35.93`, 2.0872`}, {36.429`, 2.09006`}, {36.929`, 
    2.09284`}, {37.429`, 2.09574`}, {37.928`, 2.0987`}, {38.428`, 
    2.10176`}, {38.928`, 2.10484`}, {39.428`, 2.108`}, {39.927`, 
    2.11118`}, {40.427`, 2.1147`}, {40.927`, 2.11804`}, {41.426`, 
    2.12148`}, {41.926`, 2.125`}, {42.426`, 2.13022`}, {42.925`, 
    2.1355`}, {43.425`, 2.14086`}, {43.924`, 2.14612`}, {44.424`, 
    2.15172`}, {44.924`, 2.15728`}, {45.423`, 2.16282`}, {45.923`, 
    2.16832`}, {46.423`, 2.17376`}, {46.922`, 2.17924`}, {47.422`, 
    2.18468`}, {47.921`, 2.19008`}, {48.421`, 2.19522`}, {48.921`, 
    2.20038`}, {49.42`, 2.20546`}, {49.92`, 2.2105`}, {50.419`, 
    2.2153`}, {50.919`, 2.22028`}, {51.419`, 2.2253`}, {51.918`, 
    2.23038`}, {52.418`, 2.2355`}, {52.918`, 2.24056`}, {53.417`, 
    2.24558`}, {53.917`, 2.25066`}, {54.416`, 2.25586`}, {54.916`, 
    2.26114`}, {55.416`, 2.26652`}, {55.915`, 2.272`}, {56.415`, 
    2.27796`}, {56.914`, 2.28382`}, {57.414`, 2.28976`}, {57.913`, 
    2.29606`}, {58.413`, 2.30278`}, {58.913`, 2.30994`}, {59.412`, 
    2.31844`}, {59.911`, 2.32738`}, {60.411`, 2.33684`}, {60.91`, 
    2.34626`}, {61.41`, 2.35622`}, {61.909`, 2.3666`}, {62.408`, 
    2.3781`}, {62.908`, 2.38978`}, {63.407`, 2.40206`}, {63.906`, 
    2.41488`}, {64.406`, 2.42826`}, {64.905`, 2.44164`}, {65.404`, 
    2.4556`}, {65.903`, 2.46972`}, {66.402`, 2.48462`}, {66.902`, 
    2.4995`}, {67.401`, 2.51434`}, {67.9`, 2.52918`}, {68.399`, 
    2.54446`}, {68.898`, 2.55958`}, {69.398`, 2.57466`}, {69.897`, 
    2.58976`}, {70.396`, 2.6049`}, {70.895`, 2.61992`}, {71.394`, 
    2.63486`}, {71.893`, 2.64956`}, {72.392`, 2.66406`}, {72.892`, 
    2.67816`}, {73.391`, 2.69116`}, {73.89`, 2.70374`}, {74.389`, 
    2.71524`}, {74.889`, 2.7264`}, {75.388`, 2.73692`}, {75.887`, 
    2.74714`}, {76.387`, 2.75542`}, {76.886`, 2.76298`}, {77.386`, 
    2.7694`}, {77.885`, 2.77488`}, {78.385`, 2.77826`}, {78.885`, 
    2.78076`}, {79.384`, 2.78224`}, {79.884`, 2.78344`}, {80.384`, 
    2.78336`}, {80.883`, 2.78348`}, {81.383`, 2.7834`}, {81.883`, 
    2.78342`}, {82.383`, 2.78324`}, {82.882`, 2.78326`}, {83.382`, 
    2.78336`}, {83.882`, 2.78356`}, {84.382`, 2.78408`}, {84.881`, 
    2.78456`}, {85.381`, 2.78516`}, {85.881`, 2.78588`}, {86.381`, 
    2.78704`}, {86.88`, 2.78822`}, {87.38`, 2.78946`}, {87.88`, 
    2.79078`}, {88.379`, 2.79258`}, {88.879`, 2.7942`}, {89.379`, 
    2.79588`}, {89.878`, 2.7976`}, {90.378`, 2.79952`}, {90.878`, 
    2.80144`}, {91.377`, 2.8034`}, {91.877`, 2.80536`}, {92.377`, 
    2.80736`}, {92.876`, 2.80924`}, {93.376`, 2.81112`}, {93.876`, 
    2.81304`}, {94.375`, 2.81498`}, {94.875`, 2.81704`}, {95.375`, 
    2.8192`}, {95.874`, 2.82162`}, {96.374`, 2.8246`}, {96.874`, 
    2.82786`}, {97.373`, 2.83164`}, {97.873`, 2.83588`}, {98.372`, 
    2.84056`}, {98.872`, 2.84496`}, {99.371`, 2.84936`}, {99.871`, 
    2.85372`}, {100.37`, 2.85808`}, {100.87`, 2.86238`}, {101.37`, 
    2.86658`}, {101.869`, 2.8707`}, {102.369`, 2.8748`}, {102.868`, 
    2.87864`}, {103.368`, 2.8826`}, {103.867`, 2.88658`}, {104.367`, 
    2.89052`}, {104.867`, 2.89444`}, {105.366`, 2.8984`}, {105.866`, 
    2.90244`}, {106.365`, 2.90648`}, {106.865`, 2.9106`}, {107.364`, 
    2.91472`}, {107.864`, 2.9188`}, {108.363`, 2.9228`}, {108.863`, 
    2.92664`}, {109.363`, 2.93056`}, {109.862`, 2.93438`}, {110.362`, 
    2.93796`}, {110.861`, 2.93926`}, {111.361`, 2.93994`}, {111.861`, 
    2.94062`}, {112.361`, 2.9416`}, {112.86`, 2.94238`}, {113.36`, 
    2.94324`}, {113.86`, 2.94422`}, {114.359`, 2.94532`}, {114.859`, 
    2.94666`}, {115.359`, 2.94804`}, {115.859`, 2.94956`}, {116.358`, 
    2.95122`}, {116.858`, 2.95316`}, {117.358`, 2.95502`}, {117.857`, 
    2.95714`}, {118.357`, 2.95968`}, {118.854`, 3.00818`}, {119.348`, 
    3.14064`}};
```

Which plotted together such as:

```
Show[ListPlot[data1, PlotRange -> {{20, 120}, {1.5, 3}}], ListPlot[data2]]
```

gives (without the red circles):

[image]

**Question:**

How can I get the two curves to superimposed each other as much as possible in the two regions in red (or in a given choosen two regions)?. The two regions are chosen such as the high temperature region is after the peak (more and less when the line start being constant after the peak) and before starting the peak. This can be accomplish by translating and rotating the curves.

Comment: It is not clear what are you asking. What does "superimposed curves" mean? Especially, if those curves are derived from the data you shared. Voting to close as "Needs details and clarity".

Comment: It's not clear how the curves should be changed. There are no degrees of freedom here, i.e. the data is fixed, there are no parameters, etc. It is also unclear how those curves should be brought to overlap: are you asking to selective fudge them to look the same?

Comment: @MarcoB the curves can be superimposed by either rotating or translating one of them towards the other. The degrees of freedom are rotation and translation. I hope that makes it more clear.

Comment: @AntonAntonov Superimposed is placing one curve on top of each other either by translating or by rotating the other (leaving one fixed for example). This is perfectly clear from the question. See for instance one of the answers.

Comment: @AntonAntonov thanks! I will correct the grammar there. I hope at least that from the clarification it is clear now. I appreciate your help and your comment. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I take it, that you want to translate and rotate one curve, say data1, in order to overlap it with the other curve as best as possible.

Toward this aim we first take points from data1 and data2 in the specified regions:

```
ClearAll[affTrans, err, sol];
n1 = 20; n2 = 50; n3 = 80; n4 = 110;
d1 = Join[Take[data1, {n1, n2}], Take[data1, {n3, n4}]];
d2 = Join[Take[data2, {n1, n2}], Take[data2, {n3, n4}]];
```

Then we define an affine transformation that we apply to d1:

```
affTrans[t_, r_] := (t + r.#) & /@ d1;
```

Next we define an error function that depends on translation and rotation:

```
err[{tx_, ty_}, phi_] := 
  Total[(Norm /@ (affTrans[{tx, ty}, RotationMatrix[phi]] - d2))^2];
```

Finally, we find the optimal translation and rotation using `FindMinimum`:

```
sol = {tx, ty} + RotationMatrix[phi].# & /. 
   FindMinimum[{err[{tx, ty}, phi]}, {{tx, 0}, {ty, 0}, {phi, 
       0}}][[2]];
```

Now we can plot the transformed data1 and data2:

```
ListLinePlot[{sol /@ data1, data2}]
```

[image]

You may play with n1,n2,n3,n4 and the error function if you have specific needs

Comment: Daniel thank you! But I get several errors. One is this: "FindMinimum::nrnum: The function value err[{0.,0.},0.] is not a real number at {tx,ty,phi} = {0.,0.,0.}.". Aother one is: "ReplaceAll::reps: {tx,0} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing.". What can it be?

Comment: And yes, besides from the errors that I get from the code, the curve that you show is exactly what I want.

Comment: I copied the code back from stack exchange and could reproduce your error. There was something wrong in the  line with the definition of the error function, although I you could not see what. I fixed this. Should work now.

Comment: Daniel, it's weird. I am still getting exactly the same error. I open and closed Mathematica and did it fresh but it is still not working. I also have version 12.1

Comment: Try again, I found a missing curly bracket in err[...]. Let me know if it's o.k. now

Comment: It works great now! Thank you very much Daniel !

Comment: Daniel, one last quick question: If I want to implement a third curve in your code what should I do? I am struggling a bit to expand it to more curves.

Comment: Assuming you want to transform curve data1 and data2 and leave data3 , then you define two affine transformations with two translations and two rotations.   The error function has now two parts, one for data1, the second for data 2, their sum give the total error.

Comment: Daniel, for example if I had a very simple case like: `data3 = data2 /. {x_, y_} -> {x, y + 0.3};` where `data3` is just `data2` shifted up, I dont exactly get how to implement the error here. Could you put that part as an edit in the solution if you dont mind?. Thanks

Comment: I am doing this: `d3 = Join[Take[data3, {n1, n2}], Take[data3, {n3, n4}]];
affTrans[t_, r_] := (t + r.#) & /@ d1;
err[{tx_, ty_}, phi_] := 
  Total[(Norm /@ (affTrans[{tx, ty}, RotationMatrix[phi]] - d2))^2];
sol = {tx, ty} + RotationMatrix[phi].# & /. 
   FindMinimum[{err[{tx, ty}, phi]}, {{tx, 0}, {ty, 0}, {phi, 0}}][[
    2]];
ListLinePlot[{sol /@ data1, data2, data3}, 
 PlotRange -> {All, {1.4, 3}}]` as I am trying to get something like `ListLinePlot[{sol /@ data1, data2, data3.....datan....}, `

Comment: Hello John, on seconds thoughts, in your case, it is not necessary to do it in one go, that makes it only more complicated. If you want to overlap data1 and data2 with data3, you can first do: data1 with data3 and then data2 with date3 using the code from my post. This is possible because both jobs are independent.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the procedure for 3 data sets.

I create the third data set: data3 arbitrarily by adding some noise to data1. Of course, you may take any data you like for data3. I further assume that we want to shift, as before, data1 onto data2 and new, data3 onto data2. Toward this aim, we define 2 affine translations and 2 error functions and calculation 2 solutions:

```
ClearAll[affTrans1, affTrans3, err1, err3, sol1, sol3];
n1 = 20; n2 = 50; n3 = 80; n4 = 110;
data3 = (# + {0, 0.1 RandomReal[{-1, 1}]}) & /@ data1;

d1 = Join[Take[data1, {n1, n2}], Take[data1, {n3, n4}]];
d2 = Join[Take[data2, {n1, n2}], Take[data2, {n3, n4}]];
d3 = Join[Take[data3, {n1, n2}], Take[data2, {n3, n4}]];

affTrans1[t_, r_] := (t + r.#) & /@ d1;
err1[{tx_, ty_}, phi_] := 
  Total[(Norm /@ (affTrans1[{tx, ty}, RotationMatrix[phi]] - d2))^2];
affTrans3[t_, r_] := (t + r.#) & /@ d3;
err3[{tx_, ty_}, phi_] := 
  Total[(Norm /@ (affTrans3[{tx, ty}, RotationMatrix[phi]] - d2))^2];

sol1 = {tx, ty} + RotationMatrix[phi].# & /. 
   FindMinimum[{err1[{tx, ty}, phi]}, {{tx, 0}, {ty, 0}, {phi, 
       0}}][[2]];
sol3 = {tx, ty} + RotationMatrix[phi].# & /. 
   FindMinimum[{err3[{tx, ty}, phi]}, {{tx, 0}, {ty, 0}, {phi, 
       0}}][[2]];

ListLinePlot[{sol1 /@ data1, sol3 /@ data3, data2}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much Daniel !